# How to know if logstash (or any similar product) is reading from a file?

Tags: logging, logstash

As the question states itself, is there a way to know if there is any logstash that is reading from a file? Like can i know if a logstash on some other server(lets say Server B) is reading logs from my server(lets say Server A) and if yes, what information can i get about Server B?

Answer (score 0):

Logstash do not *read* remote files, it can read local files and receive data from remote locations.

If you have a Logstash instance on Server B it will only receive from Server A if you have something in Server A sending that data, like filebeat, syslog or any other input.

To receive any data from remote locations the Logstash on Server B needs to have inputs configured saying what kind of input it is and the port that it should listen.

Depending on the way that the logs from Server A are being sent to Server B, you will have information about the ip address of Server A, the path directory of the log file and other metadata.

Can you explain a little more about your question or what you are trying to do?